# Multivariate hypergeometric distribution: Multiple bins

Tags: sampling, hypergeometric-distribution

My question concerns a variant of the classic urn problem for the case of more than 2 types (colours).

Given a single urn with $N$ balls of 3 distinct colours (say, red ($R$), green (G) and blue ($B$)), one employs the multivariate hypergeometric distribution to compute the probability $P(RGB)$ of sampling three balls without replacement, and observing exactly one ball of each colour.

I'm interested to know if there is a multivariate probability distribution for the case of $multiple$ urns.

More specifically, is there a distribution that accounts for the correlation of types (colours) of balls among $N$ urns? I suppose one can think of it as a sort of $spatial$ multivariate urn problem.

I've not been able to find anything on this site nor through a simple Google search.

Comment: There was an article I stumbled upon recently that does a similar thing, but it is looking only at probabilities of commonalities not the full distribution.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.0717.pdf

Comment: Could you describe how colors among separate urns could be "correlated"?  What kind of sampling procedure do you have in mind?

Comment: @James The paper you link to is interesting. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @whuber Since this post is almost a year old, I believe my original intent was to suppose that urns are connected via valves. An analogy here is the heart: the aortic valve allows blood flow between the left and right atriums. The atriums can be thought of as urns,